# regular expression x.group()

Tags: pandas, python-re

Please advise the step by step that leads to the results which includes below question as well. Thanks!

`df['text'].str.replace(r'(\w+day\b)', lambda x: x.groups()[0][:3])`

1. What is the transformation of `Series.str`? I can't examine it.
2. What is the `x` in `x.groups()` and what does the `groups()` do.
3. Why the `[0]` in `x.groups()[0][3]`?

Given below dataframe, df

```
0   Monday: The doctor's appointment is at 2:45pm.
1   Tuesday: The dentist's appointment is at 11:30...
2   Wednesday: At 7:00pm, there is a basketball game!
3   Thursday: Be back home by 11:15 pm at the latest.
4   Friday: Take the train at 08:10 am, arrive at ...
```

This code transform above

to

```
0          Mon: The doctor's appointment is at 2:45pm.
1       Tue: The dentist's appointment is at 11:30 am.
2          Wed: At 7:00pm, there is a basketball game!
3         Thu: Be back home by 11:15 pm at the latest.
4    Fri: Take the train at 08:10 am, arrive at 09:...
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Comment: 1.basically the pattern replaces 'day' that starts with word character and end with a word boundary...2. we are using anonymous function to get the first 3 character of the first element of the group..3. Since `groups()` retuns a tuple so by `[0]` you are getting first element of tuple and by `[:3]` you are getting first 3 character of that first element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In complement to @AnuragDabas comment, here is a breakdown of the processing using python's `re` module:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Monday: The doctor's appointment is at 2:45pm."

>>> re.search(r'(\w+day\b)', s) # find any word ending in "day"
<re.Match object; span=(0, 6), match='Monday'>

>>> re.search(r'(\w+day\b)', s).groups() # get the matching groups
('Monday',)

>>> re.search(r'(\w+day\b)', s).groups()[0] # take the first element
'Monday'

>>> re.search(r'(\w+day\b)', s).groups()[0][:3] # get the first 3 characters
'Mon'
```

When used in the context of [`pandas.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html), this passes the `lambda` to the `re.sub` function (as defined in the documentation) and uses the output as the replacement of the match (so "ABCDEFday" gets replaced with "ABC") .

description of the second parameter of `.str.replace`:

```
repl: str or callable

    Replacement string or a callable. The callable is passed the regex match object and must return a replacement string to be used. See re.sub().
```

*NB. The regex is flawed in the way that **any** word ending in `day` wil be processed. Thus if a line contained for example `Saturday: this is my birthday and not a workday!`, this would give `Sat: this is my bir and not a wor!`*